# how can i fill horizontal html list to whole column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I split a row into 2 parts with a div. I give a horizontal html list to a div with Col-6, but it only displays as much as the area it occupies. How do I make this html list fill the entire column?

```
<div class="col-6">
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-xxl justify-content-center">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Departman Onayında</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Bilgi verildi</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can fit both the box in the entire row.

```css
.list-group-item{
  background:gray;
  margin:2px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.list-group{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6">
       <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-xxl justify-content center">
                  <li class="list-group-item">Departman Onayında</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">Bilgi verildi</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```